# Calculate proportion in a nested tibble R?

Tags: r, functional-programming, dplyr

I have the following `tibble` object:

```
dt          t           uuid                data
<date>      <S3: hms>   <chr>               <list>
2018-06-23  18:25:24    0b27ea5fad61c99d    <tibble>    
2018-06-23  18:25:38    0b27ea5fad61c99d    <tibble>    
2018-06-23  18:26:01    0b27ea5fad61c99d    <tibble>
```

The `dput` version of the first observation for illustration:

```
    structure(list(dt = structure(17705, class = "Date"), t = structure(66324, class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs"), uuid = "0b27ea5fad61c99d", data = list(
    structure(list(Date = structure(c(17689, 17689, 17689, 17690, 
    17690, 17690, 17690, 17690, 17690, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 
    17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 
    17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 
    17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 
    17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 
    17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 
    17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 
    17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17692, 17693, 17693, 
    17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 
    17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 
    17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 
    17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17693, 17694, 
    17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 
    17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 
    17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 
    17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17694, 17695, 
    17695, 17695, 17695, 17695, 17695, 17695, 17695, 17695, 17695, 
    17695, 17695, 17695, 17695, 17695, 17695, 17695, 17695, 17695, 
    17695, 17695, 17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 
    17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 
    17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 
    17696, 17696, 17696, 17696, 17697, 17697, 17697, 17697, 17697, 
    17697, 17697, 17697, 17697, 17697, 17697, 17697, 17697, 17697, 
    17697, 17697, 17697, 17697, 17697, 17697, 17697, 17697, 17697, 
    17697, 17697, 17697, 17697, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 
    17698, 17698, 17698, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 
    17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 
    17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 
    17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 
    17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 17699, 
    17699, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 
    17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 
    17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 
    17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 
    17700, 17700, 17700, 17700, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 
    17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 
    17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 
    17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 
    17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 
    17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 
    17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17701, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 
    17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 
    17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 
    17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 
    17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 
    17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 
    17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 
    17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 17702, 
    17702, 17702, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 
    17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 
    17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 
    17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 
    17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 
    17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 
    17704, 17704, 17704, 17704, 17704, 17704, 17704, 17704, 17704, 
    17704), class = "Date"), Time = structure(c(76180, 77415, 
    84620, 27900, 28132, 29396, 32914, 32962, 54105, 75066, 79109, 
    79761, 79810, 79700, 80245, 80229, 80282, 80322, 14443, 23356, 
    24693, 24752, 25133, 28226, 28764, 29110, 29134, 29159, 29267, 
    33427, 34404, 34617, 34763, 35866, 35974, 36719, 39145, 38499, 
    39852, 39975, 40289, 40576, 41567, 43894, 44953, 45555, 46226, 
    46627, 46827, 46955, 47220, 46644, 47263, 47378, 47630, 47996, 
    48043, 49479, 50984, 51343, 51258, 52258, 52904, 57153, 58608, 
    58583, 58971, 59210, 61133, 61648, 62976, 63472, 63972, 67364, 
    25886, 27299, 27850, 28049, 28594, 32058, 32357, 32462, 32557, 
    32509, 35118, 35263, 35290, 37042, 38741, 40548, 40828, 42071, 
    43121, 43937, 44384, 44485, 50519, 53615, 53494, 54243, 55578, 
    57923, 58865, 59724, 64270, 68078, 69995, 71501, 71707, 71967, 
    74995, 27594, 31387, 32478, 32868, 35247, 35452, 35522, 39692, 
    40644, 40933, 43548, 44010, 44086, 47030, 47914, 49023, 49196, 
    50662, 51982, 52746, 55985, 56610, 59743, 61022, 62133, 62402, 
    62420, 63398, 63633, 67930, 68411, 73376, 76344, 80432, 82015, 
    82351, 24225, 24679, 29225, 32266, 32415, 36887, 39831, 41974, 
    42030, 42133, 46704, 47929, 54556, 57009, 57106, 56783, 57383, 
    57420, 57805, 71180, 72821, 27255, 31671, 31820, 32089, 36313, 
    39787, 43635, 44106, 44560, 46140, 46571, 46849, 51846, 52171, 
    52683, 54143, 60143, 61860, 62622, 62656, 63347, 63498, 64526, 
    64702, 64881, 64973, 67687, 67937, 68403, 25846, 27905, 27923, 
    28073, 28587, 28853, 29066, 34244, 34266, 34480, 34688, 35199, 
    35303, 36230, 36376, 39140, 47117, 47132, 49980, 50063, 55961, 
    56225, 58782, 65204, 65299, 65319, 65694, 76349, 79726, 81378, 
    81972, 82075, 82367, 84768, 84920, 24213, 24350, 24682, 27470, 
    28090, 32683, 33905, 36274, 37506, 37618, 37682, 37774, 40292, 
    40528, 42275, 42657, 43803, 44483, 45386, 45611, 45715, 45825, 
    47226, 47287, 47395, 47503, 47561, 49169, 51534, 51646, 54667, 
    54688, 54754, 54771, 54812, 54841, 54910, 55199, 55608, 56619, 
    59078, 60679, 69005, 25211, 27252, 29446, 30652, 32035, 37692, 
    37966, 38517, 40175, 40540, 41137, 43736, 43789, 43797, 43926, 
    44552, 44586, 45023, 45195, 45387, 50375, 50816, 51879, 52482, 
    54255, 55184, 56594, 57074, 57448, 57854, 58102, 58116, 58382, 
    59777, 62726, 62845, 63068, 63568, 65434, 26420, 26600, 29047, 
    29134, 29222, 29295, 29636, 30698, 32763, 34298, 34432, 34485, 
    34954, 36989, 37891, 37947, 37972, 38009, 38052, 38094, 38150, 
    38308, 38533, 40329, 41015, 41260, 42744, 42899, 43001, 43235, 
    43621, 43881, 43909, 45112, 45090, 45648, 46116, 46686, 48270, 
    48786, 50962, 51051, 51330, 51395, 53075, 53896, 54042, 54142, 
    56698, 57344, 65960, 74606, 81947, 82059, 85004, 18916, 19188, 
    19353, 19848, 22190, 22303, 22963, 26657, 27389, 28392, 29519, 
    29565, 30635, 30949, 34961, 37536, 38142, 40358, 40567, 41231, 
    41761, 41729, 41993, 42723, 45463, 46900, 47061, 47139, 47215, 
    47654, 47931, 48519, 49267, 49329, 51611, 51676, 51821, 51897, 
    52148, 51159, 52215, 52227, 52247, 53331, 53401, 54133, 54528, 
    54964, 54913, 54998, 55241, 55331, 55352, 55496, 56646, 56707, 
    56749, 56782, 56914, 57400, 57827, 58055, 58234, 59105, 59453, 
    59742, 66231, 66418, 67704, 25500, 27174, 27363, 27651, 27850, 
    28815, 28817, 28919, 29060, 29148, 32568, 32791, 32909, 33094, 
    33016, 33202, 33398, 33430, 33912, 34564, 34667, 34886, 35117, 
    35815, 36093, 43248, 43340, 43999, 44142, 44116, 44275, 44177, 
    44371, 44457, 44989, 45137, 45226, 45709, 47674, 48013, 48057, 
    48237, 48282, 48366, 48890, 54286, 55108, 56714, 57376, 59419, 
    68770, 74236, 1897, 28879, 30194, 30570, 45975, 53719, 53738, 
    57533, 58730, 69699), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), 
        phone_number = c(22881, 74049, 74049, 22881, 22881, 22881, 
        74049, 74049, 22881, 80079, 80838, 60397, 57727, 80838, 
        80838, 57727, 80838, 51122, 5444, NA, 13692, 22881, 6173, 
        22881, 22881, 86025, 86025, 86025, 86933, 86963, 62667, 
        86025, 80094, 77668, 86933, 86882, 95422, 71111, 95422, 
        80094, 22881, 77668, 77668, 86903, 22881, 77668, 35244, 
        35244, 35244, 65575, 62667, 22881, 62667, 65575, 35244, 
        22881, 22881, 71111, 22881, 77668, 22881, 22881, 61195, 
        61195, 72116, 86975, 72116, 72116, 22881, 22881, 11980, 
        22881, 22881, 22881, 11980, 60397, 11980, 60397, 22881, 
        71111, 3369, 86994, 86994, 71111, 4650, 4650, 86994, 
        11980, 80064, 80064, 60397, 4650, 80064, 61195, 4650, 
        4650, 55652, 60397, 1050, 60397, 34800, 61191, 11980, 
        11980, 86411, 0, 60397, 22881, 22881, 51122, 1050, 78335, 
        NA, 22881, 80098, 22881, 80098, 22881, 61195, 80098, 
        86865, 22881, 86903, 22881, 86013, 8473, NA, 77668, 77668, 
        80111, 86865, 22881, 22881, NA, 22881, 66655, 66655, 
        22881, 22881, 77668, NA, 1050, 80838, NA, 6173, 6173, 
        5444, 6173, 6173, 8473, 84091, 21383, 21383, 86882, NA, 
        61191, 61191, 4500, 86882, 66655, 74049, 74049, 1050, 
        74049, 74049, 80838, 11980, 76532, 22881, 33555, 33555, 
        86903, NA, NA, 61195, 61195, 61195, NA, 80064, 80111, 
        NA, 86903, 94801, 80064, 11980, 22881, 22881, 22881, 
        22881, 22881, 22881, 22222, 68804, 68804, 22881, 22881, 
        22881, 22881, 22881, 22881, 22881, 68804, 68804, 22881, 
        68804, 68804, 68804, 68804, 68804, 22881, 22881, 22881, 
        74049, 74049, 74049, 80838, 74049, 29227, 29227, 74049, 
        29227, 29227, 29227, 60397, 9525, 9525, 22881, 50528, 
        50528, 22881, 50528, 50528, 50528, 50528, 50528, 22881, 
        78335, 84091, 21383, 1050, NA, 1050, 86882, 1050, 25987, 
        61195, 80079, 86882, 86865, 86903, 65633, 5701, 78335, 
        86850, 86882, 68695, 22881, 79521, 79521, 22881, 86882, 
        65633, 84091, 84091, 84091, 90772, 80064, 84091, 80064, 
        84091, 22881, 86963, 10869, 22881, 22881, 77668, 22881, 
        22881, 5477, 77668, 54963, 22881, 77668, 21383, 22881, 
        77326, 86903, 86963, 86963, 78335, 86903, 21383, 86903, 
        86903, 86963, 77668, 86882, 80062, 80062, 49296, 7067, 
        4650, 4650, 22881, 61195, 61195, 61195, 22881, 51122, 
        22881, 61195, 51122, 80098, 22881, 22881, 22881, 5444, 
        77668, 5444, 77668, 77668, 35244, 62667, 78877, 77668, 
        22881, 86411, 4650, 76723, 68695, 68695, 35244, 77668, 
        77668, 35244, 9875, 86948, 76532, 62667, 13077, 62667, 
        62667, 62667, 80064, 62667, 77668, 86903, 90772, 77668, 
        62667, 62667, 61195, 62236, 86903, 77668, 77668, 77668, 
        86882, 62667, 77668, 77668, 77668, 24120, 77668, 22881, 
        60397, 50528, 50528, 50528, 63560, 63560, 63560, 63560, 
        50528, 50528, 50528, 11980, 11980, 22881, 80079, 86882, 
        6209, 77668, 63043, 86882, 73146, 86882, 84091, 73146, 
        86865, 73146, 86865, 86979, 62236, 86963, 58090, 62667, 
        58090, 7067, 86963, 4650, 4650, 86882, 21383, 21383, 
        62667, 62667, 21383, 9232, 62667, 21383, 62667, 86903, 
        86903, 86903, 86882, 86865, 85833, 86865, 61195, 84091, 
        84091, 22881, 3000, 22881, 85833, 85833, 51122, 51122, 
        85833, 22881, 22881, 22881, 57727, 22881, 22881, 22881, 
        22881, 22881, 22881, 22881, 1050, 1050, 84091, 84091, 
        22881, 84091, 61195, 80062, 72116, 65575, 31620, 65575, 
        31620, 80079, 80064, 80064, 53329, NA, 4650, 22881, 22881, 
        86882, 61195, 86882, 61195, 13077, 61195, 61195, 86882, 
        13077, 13077, 86903, 86882, 72116, 72116, 61195, 61195, 
        5595, 5595, 61195, 5431, 22881, 86903, 86903, 21383, 
        61195, 61195, 84219, 0, 95422, 22881, 22881, 22881, 90849, 
        22881, 22881, 22881, 11980, 22881), isInContact = c(TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
        FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
        FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
        FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
        TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
        TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), callDuration = c(1, 0, 0, 71, 
        13, 54, 0, 315, 135, 87, 34, 0, 0, 233, 0, 3249, 3193, 
        3142, 10, 11, 0, 117, 0, 59, 137, 0, 0, 0, 1, 33, 27, 
        85, 0, 7, 145, 23, 0, 1039, 25, 305, 0, 0, 35, 58, 21, 
        110, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 601, 98, 228, 349, 0, 526, 1045, 
        0, 5, 515, 167, 76, 30, 0, 65, 112, 100, 0, 215, 362, 
        0, 301, 109, 1379, 0, 199, 532, 10, 8, 83, 0, 0, 1563, 
        130, 23, 116, 0, 0, 0, 505, 146, 71, 0, 17, 107, 0, 0, 
        732, 670, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 280, 0, 61, 0, 0, 21, 34, 
        68, 126, 0, 0, 49, 81, 12, 0, 0, 35, 196, 16, 0, 33, 
        0, 24, 88, 181, 0, 0, 24, 146, 163, 10, 0, 87, 52, 24, 
        1208, 946, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 82, 48, 130, 1769, 0, 
        0, 242, 52, 209, 35, 0, 0, 567, 0, 126, 900, 0, 0, 257, 
        93, 95, 8, 17, 33, 0, 23, 15, 237, 116, 25, 16, 56, 6, 
        0, 619, 119, 0, 163, 0, 73, 107, 154, 0, 56, 0, 0, 58, 
        44, 0, 0, 43, 0, 29, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 15, 60, 
        0, 66, 52, 11, 53, 79, 106, 0, 0, 112, 872, 0, 308, 0, 
        0, 0, 172, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 39, 18, 126, 39, 0, 34, 0, 
        48, 1462, 56, 0, 0, 105, 300, 0, 27, 75, 22, 51, 38, 
        71, 0, 0, 20, 0, 24, 7, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 16, 232, 
        74, 66, 108, 272, 0, 695, 25, 14, 25, 215, 0, 9, 183, 
        540, 6, 29, 0, 41, 51, 0, 8, 0, 22, 26, 29, 42, 0, 85, 
        8, 52, 107, 23, 14, 62, 0, 29, 0, 44, 91, 143, 15, 89, 
        144, 0, 0, 11, 69, 10, 106, 49, 65, 94, 33, 39, 0, 804, 
        17, 34, 0, 29, 61, 15, 38, 65, 62, 15, 58, 109, 394, 
        85, 17, 21, 91, 62, 8, 30, 0, 34, 83, 56, 121, 32, 88, 
        79, 0, 172, 101, 75, 0, 40, 35, 363, 44, 0, 111, 0, 0, 
        0, 33, 0, 100, 85, 0, 0, 0, 88, 528, 364, 0, 91, 31, 
        60, 162, 6, 0, 66, 34, 0, 0, 250, 501, 66, 18, 0, 46, 
        8, 71, 13, 71, 0, 38, 68, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1040, 0, 17, 
        124, 0, 354, 60, 218, 0, 79, 109, 56, 0, 133, 653, 22, 
        0, 0, 14, 0, 105, 11, 0, 2, 220, 76, 174, 0, 24, 113, 
        22, 30, 269, 0, 925, 0, 16, 43, 26, 80, 0, 82, 0, 0, 
        110, 0, 0, 25, 17, 47, 19, 12, 0, 40, 21, 0, 27, 49, 
        0, 41, 0, 174, 0, 85, 36, 0, 0, 9, 0, 17, 0, 0, 35, 57, 
        150, 0, 133, 18, 0, 169, 129, 0, 0, 88, 62, 142, 433, 
        0, 4, 0, 1, 1)), .Names = c("Date", "Time", "phone_number", 
    "isInContact", "callDuration"), row.names = c(NA, -500L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame")))), .Names = c("dt", "t", "uuid", "data"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Now I want to calculate the proportion of the `isInContact == 1`:

```
df %>% mutate(tmp = lapply(data, pull, var = isInContact),
              prop_in_contact = mean(tmp == TRUE))
```

But this doesn't work, please advise what I am missing here?
I would like to understand the principal and the logic behind your answer to learn how to perform such tasks in the future.
Every time I am trying to calculate it it behaves different.

Expected output:

```
    dt          t           uuid                data        data_is_in_contact_prop_TRUE 
    <date>      <S3: hms>   <chr>               <list>    <double>
    2018-06-23  18:25:24    0b27ea5fad61c99d    <tibble>  0.87    
    2018-06-23  18:25:38    0b27ea5fad61c99d    <tibble>  0.01  
    2018-06-23  18:26:01    0b27ea5fad61c99d    <tibble>  0.9
```

Comment: Please post expected output

Comment: @Sotos done, sorry missed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possibility using `purrr::map_dbl`

```
df %>%
    mutate(frac_isInContact = map_dbl(
        data, 
        ~sum(.x$isInContact == TRUE) / length(.x$isInContact)))
## A tibble: 1 x 5
#  dt         t      uuid             data               frac_isInContact
#  <date>     <time> <chr>            <list>                        <dbl>
#1 2018-06-23 18:25  0b27ea5fad61c99d <tibble [500 × 5]>            0.878
```

Explanation: We use `map_dbl` to calculate the fraction of `TRUE` entries in `data$isInContact`.

Comment: The .x is for what? What is the meaning of .x?

Comment: @steves In `map`s formula notation, `.x` refers to the first argument, which corresponds to the first entry from column `data` (which is a `tibble`). Take a look at [the map documentation](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! Your easy, professional and efficient answer solved my issue.
My pleasure to e-meet you and get Your answer!

Comment: You're very welcome @steves; glad to help! Good luck with your work!